# What is the difference between IBM MQ's IsOpen and OpenStatus properties on a queue?

Tags: java, c#, message-queue, ibm-mq

The [MQQueue](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q111260_.htm?lang=en) object in IBM MQ has properties  `MQQueue.IsOpen` and `MQQueue.OpenStatus`. Both are inherited from the [MQManagedObject](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q111210_.htm?lang=en) class.  What do these properties represent and what are the differences between them?  Do they show, for example, whether the queue is open for `GET`, `PUT` or both?

Unfortunately the docs aren't very clear on these properties. The most helpful description I found are below. Note that these are taken from the ActiveX reference so I don't know how applicable they are.

[Source](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q034160_.htm?lang=en)

> **IsOpen property**
>
> Returns whether the queue is open.
>
> Read-only.

[Source](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q034250_.htm?lang=en)

> **OpenStatus property**
>
> Read-only. Indicates if the queue is opened or not. Initial value is TRUE after AccessQueue method or FALSE after New.

In a next step I debugged the `amqmdnet.dll` which showed the following implementations for the properties:

```
public bool IsOpen
{
  get
  {
    return this.objectHandle != null && this.objectHandle.HOBJ != null && (this.objectHandle.HOBJ.Handle != 0 && -1 != this.objectHandle.HOBJ.Handle);
  }
}

public bool OpenStatus
{
  get
  {
    bool flag = false;
    if (this.qMgr != null && this.qMgr.IsConnected)
      flag = !this.isClosed;
    return flag;
  }
}
```

Although I tend toward using `OpenStatus` I'm still looking for educated advice. I'm especially unsure what the `IsOpen` property actually represents. Is it relevant when telling whether the queue instance is open for put and get calls?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand why you don't know that you have already called the AccessQueue method?

Comment: @MoragHughson You're right, the queue has to be open when calling the AccessQueue method initially. But conditions can change, right? Consider the queue manager has been stopped (manually or by error). I want to know this before an MQException pops up.

Comment: Why?  And that is the whole point of exception handling.  Something went wrong with the connection or open queue  and your code should handle this condition. i.e. retry logic/reconnect logic

Comment: @Roger I see, exception handling was a bad example. Anyway, the use case here doesn't matter for me. I think it's a valid to question how to tell both properties apart.

Comment: "I think it's a valid to question how to tell both properties apart."  Yes, it is.  I'll edit the post so it actually asks that question. However, you answer the question as worded with your comment that "conditions can change, right?" There will always be a race condition between checking the status of the queue and making an API call against it during which the status could change. Therefore the status check is of little practical use but exception handling on a bad return code is essential. If this is a code golf question, roll my edits back and we can explore checking the status.

Answer (score 3):

I dont think there's any better documentation, but in effect:

IsOpen tells you if the open call itself has been successful, ie there is an associated handle being maintained for the queue.

OpenStatus tells you whether there is a valid connection to the queue manager AND the object is also open.

From that, I'd probably veer towards OpenStatus as you suggest, if you want to know if there is a best chance of using the object. I would also echo Morag and Roger's comments, that better exception handling and understanding of state should be a far better approach.